# What to do with an off-topic tag with a lot of off-topic questions inside?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

Recently a question regarding Far Manager pops up on SO and I've voted to close it. However while looking at the related questions on the right I saw many similar questions.

I opened many of them and saw that they all have the [far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/far) tag. The tag currently has only 21 questions (I've just removed a question from it) but it even has a wiki inside

> Far Manager is a program for managing files and archives in Windows operating systems (http://farmanager.com). For questions related to far pointers use 'pointers' tag.

I've checked all of them and was really surprised that none of them is about programming and should be on super user instead. There's also a corresponding tag on SU: [far-manager](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/far-manager)

So what should we do with the tag and its questions? IMHO we should close all the questions and move them to SU if possible

Comment: You would need to get mod(s) at Super User to agree ahead of time if you're wanting to migrate multiple questions.

Comment: @BSMP of course I don't have migrating permissions. And since I don't like to vote to close all of them manually, I'm opening this discussion to see how we should deal with them

Comment: I meant that it'd be better to bring them into this meta discussion ahead of time rather than flooding their queue (? I'm not actually sure how they see these) with a bunch of migration requests. However, taking a look at the tag there are only 4 that are recent enough for a migration attempt anyway.

Comment: @Makoto: I see 21 questions in that tag. Are you sure you checked the correct one?

Comment: @BDL:  So I'm going to sheepishly take that L and say that I had a filter on.  Ignore me...

Comment: As someone stuck for the rest of his life de-crapifying the seo and kali-linux tags, I'd suggest closing the browser tab and walking away.

Comment: As far as the general guideline for migration, would these questions add any value to Super User? If not, then there's probably no case for migration. You might find a couple that are worthy of migration, but they will be few and far between because if the user didn't know enough about the Stack Exchange Network to make the question on topic here on Stack Overflow where they posted it initially, it's not too likely that it will happen to be a well-asked question for Super User. I bet just cleaning up the tag and closing will be the way we go about this unless we find some real gems.

Comment: At a glance, some of those 21 questions *might* squeak by under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" part of [our topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen a few of them might, there were 4 or 5 I wasn't certain of; the remainder were all clearly superuser stuff

Comment: If this does go as far as a burnination post "This tag goes too Far"?

Answer (score 10):

The first step is always posting a question on Meta, so you're already on the right track. Per the [FAQ on tag burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/2756409), for a tag with fewer than 50 questions, you can follow the expedited burnination process:

> 1. If you have **authoritative** knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have **conferred** with at least one other [trusted community member](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), and are dealing with a tag that has a **small number** of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little *ad hoc* help.

This tag meets those criteria, so in this case, you could reach out to the Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers at the [SOCVR chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask for assistance/guidance.

Alternatively, if you are in contact with a trusted user already, the two (or more) of you could go ahead and start working on cleaning up/close-voting the questions, removing the tag from questions that have more than one tag, and adding correct/relevant tags to questions with only the [far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/far) tag where possible.